# Constructing version string with C++ preprocessor from separate components

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to construct a sort of version string in forms v.vv and "v.vv" (with/without quotes) from components. Here's my example code

```
#define A 1
#define B 00
#define X(a,b) a.b
X(A,B)
```

GCC gives me

```
1 . 00
```

i.e. with some spaces. 
Is there a way to make it without spaces? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to have the version as a string, then you can do e.g.

```
#define Y(v) #v
#define X(a,b) Y(a) "." Y(b)
```

Using the `X` macro will now create the string `"1.00"`.